# Объединить два приложения в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

У меня два приложения, оба распространяются бесплатно. В процессе развития пришел к тому, что функционал первого приложения "влился" во второе. Хотелось бы остановить развитие первого проекта (закрыв его в GP), а аудиторию перевести на второе. Это возможно технически или организационно?

Comment: Тут советы от гугла по сливанию приложений https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/engage/migrate-merge-apps?hl=ru

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В магазине всё завязано на bundle id приложений. Организационно это не сделать.

Обновите одно из приложений, чтоб при запуске показывалось окно с текстом, что вы объединяете приложения и ссылкой на другое приложение. Постепенно люди таким образом перетекут в новое приложение.

Comment: Спасибо, думал над этим. Так и сделаю